# Install apt-dater-host on CentOS-Systems using puppet

Tags: centos, puppet, yum, puppetmaster, puppet-foreman

I would like to install apt-dater-host on Debian **and** CentOS-based systems using puppet and foreman.

On Debian the package is available on the standard repos - but on CentOs this is not the case - I used RPM-search and got the following [result](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23572345/dir/centos_6/com/apt-dater-host-yum-0.9.0-1.2.i686.rpm.html).

How can I install the package using yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CentOS, you'll need to find a yum repository that holds the package, and then add it to the system using the Puppet `yumrepo` resource.

```
class aptdater {

  if $::osfamily == 'RedHat' {

    # Only install the yum repo on RH-family systems
    yumrepo { 'blah':
      ...
    }

    # Override the package to require the yum repo to be deployed first
    Package['apt-dater-host'] {
      require => Yumrepo['blah'],
    }
  }

  package { 'apt-dater-host':
    ensure => present,
  }
}
```